# Dealing with different String date formats

Tags: java

In java, I have a string with a date in dd-mm-yyyy format:

```
String value = "31-01-1989";
```

Now, I want the value in another variable to be ddmmyyyy format:

```
String value = "31011989";
```

How to do this?

Comment: is this an example, or do you just want to remove all the dashes from a string?

Comment: Do *what*, exactly? Presumably you want to convert from this format into something else, but do you know the format of any specific string?

Comment: I want to remove the dashes from the string

Comment: Are you working with this particular format, or do you want to know how to convert from one date format to another?

Comment: @Maverick: Well that would just be a matter of using `value = value.replace("-", "");` - but is that *really* what you want to do? It seems more likely that you want to parse different formats.

Comment: Of course, to just remove the dashes would imply that "31-1-1989" be converted to an "3111989".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you can simply remove dashes

```
value = value.replace("-", "");
```

or

```
value = value.replaceAll("-", "");
```

but according to my tests the first version is a little bit faster. So  I personally prefer to use replaceAll only when the first parameter is a regex.

Note that, despite a confusion in the names, `String.replace` replaces ALL substrings that match the first arg, just as `String.replaceAll` does. The main difference is that the `String.replace` treats the first arg as a string literal and `String.replaceAll` uses it as a regex.

Comment: You'll need to use `replaceAll`. Edit: I'm wrong. I improperly assumed that the existence of both `replace` and `replaceAll` meant something. `replace` is used to replace `chars`, and `replaceAll` for substrings.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev : From the API doc of `replace`: "Returns a new string resulting from *replacing all occurrences* of oldChar in this string with newChar."

Comment: @Fildor it is actually for replace(char oldChar, char newChar)

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev you're right. Copied the wrong one. But effect is the same, also the CharSequence-Version replaces all occurrences.

Answer (score 4):

easy solution:

```
String value1 = "31-01-1989";
String value2 = value1.replace("-", "");
```

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev.. No. It isn't.

Comment: `''` isn't a valid character literal. You should be using `replace("-", "")`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for a general solution. Write a `SimpleDateFormat` to [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) the first date and use [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29) in another to have the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.replace(Charseq, Charseq)` to remove the delimiters.

```
String value = "31-01-1989";
String value2 = value.replace("-", "");
System.out.println(value2);
```

Comment: Why would you want to introduce regular expressions into the mix? `replace` is much simpler.

Comment: @JonSkeet true, but replaceAll was the first thing that came to my mind.. :)